# Read settings in another section than values

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have following settings file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "UniquePermisionsQueueConnStr": "xx",
    "UniquePermisionsQueueName": "spo-unique-permissions-reporting",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "CosmosDB": {
    "UniquePermisionsQueueConnStr": "xx"
  }
}
```

I can read the settings in the values section without any props by using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UniquePermisionsQueueName"]; or Environment...

However how do I get the values in the CosmosDB section? I tried ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CosmosDB:UniquePermisionsQueueName"] but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `Values` section is injected into Environment variables by Azure Function runtime, hence we got nothing for other section.

We need to read the Json file as usual. Add `ExecutionContext context` in function method signature and try code below.

```
var r = new StreamReader(context.FunctionAppDirectory+"/local.settings.json");
var myJson = r.ReadToEnd();
dynamic config =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson);
var cosmosDBSettings = config.CosmosDB as JObject;
var uniquePermisionsQueueConnStr = cosmosDBSettings.GetValue("UniquePermisionsQueueConnStr").ToString();
```

As for deployment to Azure, `local.settings.json` is for local dev, which is not uploaded to Azure by default. We should remove `<CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>` in `<functionname>.csproj`(Right click on project and `Edit <functionname>.csproj`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Highly appreciated.